# How to send the nested json in POST Request via postman

Tags: json, nested, postman

I am writing project with Java Play Framework 2.5,

and I want to do POST request with nested json via postman

I need to do something like below:

```
{lesson:{
   "id":1,
   "name":"Biology"
}}
```

Comment: I think your question is not complete. Also, which postman are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem,

the problem was in Java code.

Whenever you get the data from the http, you need to convert it by this way:

```
String jsonToString = new String(mainJson.get("lesson").toString());
```

not by this:

```
Object jsonToString = mainJson.get("lesson").toString()
```

Also, in postman, I did it as [sysquare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5819195/sysquare) mentioned

Comment: You could have mentioned your Java code too in that question. But you mentioned about only how to pass such nested json in postman and so was my answer limited to that.

Glad that you solved it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

in value field of postman, write the json format
like

```
{key:value}
```

Comment: yes, i did so. but Java cant convert it to JSONObject